# kendo ui change event not working on Treeview with remote data

Tags: events, kendo-ui, treeview

For me the change event in Treeview not getting called when selecting the node on treeview as like in this [kendo demo site](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/treeview/events.html) .My Treeview loads data remotely. we are using Kendo ui web  only . Could you please  give me suggestion or a demo on fiddle would be a great help.Thanks in Advance

My JSP code

```
                    function onChange(e) {
                        console.log("Selection changed");
                    }


  var homogeneous = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
                        transport: {
                            read: {
                                url: '<c:url value="/welcome/list/"/>',
                                dataType: "json"
                            }
                        },

                        schema: {
                            model: {
                                 hasChildren: "hasFiles",
                                children: "items"
                            }
                        }
                            });



               var tv= $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
                    dataSource: homogeneous, 
                    dataTextField: "text",
                      change: onChange});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used your code and the [remote binding demo](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/treeview/remote-data.html) to create [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/OdUmUqah/1/edit) which seems to work. Here is the related code:

```
var homogeneous = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
  transport: {
    read: {
      url: "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/Employees",
      dataType: "jsonp"
    }
  },
  schema: {
    model: {
      id: "EmployeeId",
      hasChildren: "HasEmployees"
    }
  }
});

$("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
  dataSource: homogeneous,
  dataTextField: "FullName",
  change: function() {
    alert("Selection change");
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply .Sorry I forget to mention ..Its working in  jsbin but Not in jsfiddle and in my Application as well.I dont have any error and clue for it.